# E.E. Rule-based product relations. I must save the product before the rule will apply

Tags: ee-1.14.2.0, targetrule

I'm integrating rule-based product relations. In the process, from the admin product grid, I applied an action whose job is to remove all related products. It did it's job, but it did it too well. I thought it would remove only the related products that were manually assigned. It did that as well as trick Magento into believing that none of the target rules applied to it. If I open the product and click save, the rule re-applies and is functional. Now I have to go through every product and save them one by one in order for the rule to work<strike>, or, untested, remove the rule and create a new rule</strike>.

Is there anyway to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the database structure it's pretty basic data, no flag to indicate something is added manually or by the system so in short: **no**

You could add an extra column from a custom module and add an`before_save` observer that determines if the relation being saved is manual or something the system does but this will require quite some programming I think

Comment: What it looks like I will need to do is either go through each product one-by-one and save each by clicking the save button or loop through the products programatically and simulate this action. Are you able to guide me towards the method that would simulate the product save button? The default bulk update feature does not work.